# Как в Spring MVC вынести отдельно дублируйщийся код?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

## Ситуация:

На сайте есть меню и в нём отображается имя и фамилия пользователя. Имя и фамилия берется из БД. На данный момент я использую следующий код (который дублируется на всём моем сайте):

```java
    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView main(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        
        /* Начало дублирования кода */
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(auth.isAuthenticated()){
           modelAndView.addObject("customerName", customerService.getCustomerNameByEmail(auth.getName()));
        }
        /* Конец дублирования кода */

        modelAndView.setViewName("main");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

## Вопрос:

Как вынести дублирующийся код так, чтобы одной строкой его вызывать, и он автоматически добавлялся в контроллер ИЛИ ЖЕ чтобы он сам при создании контроллера добавлялся?

Comment: Вынести дублирующийся код в отдельный метод?

Comment: Этот код вообще не нужен, проверку аутентификации и получение вашего `customerName` можно сделать в шаблоне.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Как это сделать? Я не понимаю, что значит шаблон в данном случае

Comment: В `setViewName` вы имя чего передаёте?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev имя html-файла (Thymeleaf использую) - `main.html`

Comment: Если Spring Security правильно используется, то в main.html в нужном месте можно просто написать `<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()"><div th:text="${#authentication.customerName}"></div></sec:authorize>` и получить желаемый результат. Максимум `AuthenticationProvider` придётся переопределить.